# Logic sentence conditions

Tags: logic

We were asked to find the logic sentence:

> All small triangles are left of all squares.

My answer:

$$\forall x: \mathrm{Small}(x)\wedge\mathrm{Triangle}(x)\Rightarrow\forall y: \mathrm{Square}(y)\wedge\mathrm{LeftOf}(x,y)$$

The software, however, has simulated a case where my sentence is untrue. Apparently, when there is a small triangle but no squares, my formula gives back true even though it should be untrue?

Graphically represented scenario where my formula is true, but the demanded logical sentence is untrue:

[image: Graphically represented scenario where my formula is true, but the demanded logical sentence is untrue.]

Comment: Do you mean $$(\forall x: \mathrm{Small}(x)\wedge\mathrm{Triangle}(x))\Rightarrow(\forall y: \mathrm{Square}(y)\wedge\mathrm{LeftOf}(x,y))$$ or $$\forall x: (\mathrm{Small}(x)\wedge\mathrm{Triangle}(x)\Rightarrow\forall y: \mathrm{Square}(y)\wedge\mathrm{LeftOf}(x,y))$$?
They are both wrong, but in different ways. We need to know to give you an answer.

Comment: The second one, the first one you would have no bound x for the sentence behind the implication which invalidates the formula, no?

Comment: Well, no, both formulas are logically valid, but like I said, both are wrong, so I didn't know which one you meant. It's always better to be on the safe side to over, rather than underuse parentheses.

Comment: $\forall x \forall y \ [(\text {Tr}(x) \land \text {Small}(x) \land \text {Sq}(y)) \to \text {LeftOf}(x,y)]$

Comment: It is similar to "All men are mortals": the main connective must be $\to$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second statement reads as follows:

> For every $x$, it is true that if $x$ is a small triangle, then every $y$ is a square, and $x$ is to the left of every $y$.

This statement can actually only be true if no small triangles exist, since, if one small triangle exists, then the sentence "all $y$ are squares to the left of $x$" must be true, but that sentence cannot be true for $y=x$ (assuming, of course, that a small triangle cannot at the same time be a square, much less to the left of itself...)

Comment: Oh I got it, thank you!

Comment: @LLScheme If this answer is what you needed, don't forget to upvote and accept it.

Comment: Didn't realize, done now, thank you once again.